# How cloud I select the jsonb[] contains one of string in array by prisma?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, orm, prisma

for example, I had dataset like below:

| id | groups |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `['A']` |
| 2 | `['B']` |
| 3 | `['A', 'C']` |
| 4 | `['B', 'D']` |
| 5 | `['C']` |
| 6 | `['D']` |
| 7 | `['A', 'B']` |

And I want select groups contain one of `['A' | 'B']`.
The result must be id `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]`.

The raw sql present like `(groups)::jsonb ?| array['A', 'B']`.

I use the ORM way like below:

```
const chosen = await prisma.table.findMany({
    where: {
      groups: {
          array_contains: ['A', 'B']
      }
    }
})
```

but the result I got only the `id:7`.

this is not what I want...

How could I implement my theory by way of ORM?

Comment: You need to use the `OR` operator because `array_contains` checks if _all_ elements inside the array exists in the record

Comment: Hi @Nullndr , thanks for your answer~ I had recognized this problem and solved it. haha

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

use OR to union conditions.

```
const chosen = await prisma.table.findMany({
    where: {
        OR: [
            {
                groups: {
                    array_contains: ['A']
                }
            },
            {
                groups: {
                    array_contains: ['B']
                }
            },
        ]
    }
})
```